# Jaccard Index returning all 1's

Tags: python

```
def jaccard_distance(x,y):
  intersection_cardinality = len(set.intersection(*[set(x), set(y)]))
  union_cardinality = len(set.union(*[set(x), set(y)]))
  return intersection_cardinality/float(union_cardinality)
```

For some reason when I'm running this with my data matrix, it is returning all 1's.  Does anyone know what i am doing wrong?

Comment: Please provides python version, list1 and list2.

Comment: Python 3.something. List 1 and 2 each contain the same 10 rows of 1's and 0's. IE:
Row 1: 1; 0; 0; 0; 1
Row 2: 0; 0; 1; 0; 1

Comment: Add the full definition to your code, in order to provide a reproductible working code.

Comment: You're method is called `jaccard_distance`, but computes the Jaccard Index (not necessarily why it's wrong, just a little inconsistent)

Answer (score 1):

This code seems to work:

```
def jaccard_index(x,y):
  intersection_cardinality = len(set.intersection(*[set(x), set(y)]))
  union_cardinality = len(set.union(*[set(x), set(y)]))
  return intersection_cardinality/float(union_cardinality)


jaccard_distance((1, 2, 3), (3, 4, 5))   # return 0.2
jaccard_distance((1, 2, 3), (6, 4, 5))   # return 0.0
jaccard_distance((1, 2, 3), (1, 2, 3))   # return 1.0
```

---

#### about the code

This expression:

```
set.intersection(*[set(x), set(y)])
```

Is awfully complex, and could be simplified to:

```
set(x) & set(y)  # or set(x).intersection(set(y))
```

Under Python 3, the float casting is unnecessary:

```
>>> 1 / 3
0.333333333333
```

The creation of the initial list is complicated, and may leads to error.
These should replace them efficiently:

```
numbers = []
with open('jarticl.csv','rt', errors='replace') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader = csv.reader(f):
         numbers.append(tuple(row[i] for i in range(1, 6)))

art1, art2, art3, art4, art5 = zip(*numbers)
```

Comment: thanks for the help! switching it to setx & y fixed it some how.